Can't export pdf file in size 7000x1000 mm
I have project in inkscape, that will be print, so it's dimension/size is 1:1, when I try to export it to PDF I got blank page, small version exported properly, but real size doesn't. The dimension of desired pdf is 7000mmx1000m.
Also when I try to save as pdf in such dimension, I got blank white page.
Can someone help/explain this?
Cheers!


Maximum page dimensions for PDF 1.3 and earlier (<= Acrobat 4) is 45" x 45?
Maximum page dimensions for PDF 1.4 and later (>= Acrobat 5) is 200" x 200"

7000mm = 275.5" - PDF does not support a page 275" in size.

Yes, I've just learnt that. Thanks for quick answer!
